# Object glitching/dissapearing in render

Tags: rendering, objects, rigid-body-simulation, parent, groups

I have completed my animation but I realised when I render it that one of the propellers blades starts to glitch. On some frames it is in shot and some it is out of shot and this is really strange. These 'blades' are both parented to the same 'propeller' and the 'propeller' is parented to the middle ball. I have baked the animation through so this shouldn't be a problem. These propellers are passive rigid bodies.

I have tried to figure out this problem and I just can't get to a solution. I've never had it where a rigid body object glitches out like that in the rendered animation, it's almost like it's jumping, which on the render these frames show the object as invisible. The videos attached will show. https://i.imgur.com/IhKCTeW.mp4 https://i.imgur.com/YZmsaHr.png

Comment: Hi, is this different than the [first question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204347/object-glitching-dissapearing-in-render-due-to-parenting-problems) you asked? Please edit your original question and clarify it's meaning instead of posting the same question multiple times. Thanks

Comment: See [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)